# Posting same content on two different domains

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, canonical-url

Just a quick question can I post the same content on two different domains and do a `canonical` to the primary domain from second domain without my primary domain getting penalized for duplicate content?

Can anything bad happen by doing this?

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, Google's panda update penalized this sort of behavior and Google recommends that publishers preferably not do this but if they need to, indicate the behavior in their Google Webmaster console by registering canonical urls/domains

For more information, please check the following links:

[1]https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2008/09/demystifying-duplicate-content-penalty.html
[2] https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en

Comment: Thanks AJ, I read your links, you see the thing is I have one domain (lets call it domain A) where I produce my content on, which I want to rank for, however domain B I don't care about rankings but get 1000s of visitors through social media on domain `B` since it is already an established brand, Both domains are in the same nice. I don't see what is the problem if I clearly tell Google via a `canonical` that the content on domain `B` originated from domain `A` can you see a problem with that?

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee If they are the same content, what is your reasoning for using 2 domains? Can't you just 301 the domain B into the domain A?

Comment: I second the 301, however, you will not be penalized for a canonical tag from one domain to another. It is not recommended of course, however, duplicate content will exist from time to time and the canonical tag is intended to solve the problem of knowing which content is the original (preferred) and not penalizing content for being duplicate.

Comment: The reason for not wanting to do a 301 is because domain `A` is an established brand, however we still want to feed our readers with new content, whith Domain `B` we are in the process of developing, thus producing content on it, trying to get it to rank but also giving our established visitors on A new info every now and then